# consulta sql no muestra dato habiendo registros

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando crear esta consulta:

```
    select bonos.codBono, users.nombre, bonos.tipo, bonos.minutos, bonos.precio, 
    contratan.tiempoRestanteBono, contratan.bonoSolicitado as bonoSolicitado, 
    contratan.tiempoSolicitado
    from contratan
    INNER join users on contratan.usuario = users.id
    INNER join bonos on contratan.bono = bonos.codBono
    where activo = 0
    and (SELECT tipo from bonos, contratan where contratan.bonoSolicitado = bonos.codBono )
```

Y necesito que muestre el tipo de bono solicitado. En contratan guardo el código de bono solicitado
y estoy intentando que me muestre el tipo de ese bono... pero siempre me aparece el código. Esto es para hacer un update de una tabla, para qeu cuando el usuario cambie de bono, se le cambie el tipo

El resultado de salida debería de ser algo así:

```
codBono nombre tipo minutos precio tiempoRestanteBono bonoSolicitado tiempoSolicitado
   6    David Serrano Alonso 10Min 10 9.00 1(aquí es donde debe aparecer el tipo) 30
```

Es que luego, hago una tabla dinámica con vueJS y no puedo acceder a la propiedad bonoSolicitado
y para que aparezca el nombre del nuevo bono que el cliente solicita, necesito esa consulta o similar.. No se si me estoy explicando correctamente. Adjunto la estructura de mi DB

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla users:**

```
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nif` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email_verified_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `perfil` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'usuario',
  `telefono` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `nif`, `nombre`, `email`, `email_verified_at`, `password`, `direccion`, `perfil`, `telefono`, `remember_token`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, '45921676z', 'David Serrano Alonso', 'daviserraalonso@gmail.com', NULL, '$2y$10$nZcz5O3MaE/F/ML0QSC7M.1/fe.6QYdd11Faa1Wnsh.E4TiZR3xcW', NULL, 'usuario', 652138927, NULL, '2020-11-20 09:19:46', '2020-11-20 09:19:46'),
(2, '45921676z', 'Admin', 'daviserraalonso@hotmail.com', '2020-11-20 10:29:35', '$2y$10$wxOoOy1hlc8JYnozGKy.ReNwT3Q24akiltSyfrGYJ39wjud72lH7a', NULL, 'tecnico', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

--
```

**Tabla HistorialBonos:**

```
    CREATE TABLE `historialbonos` (
  `codHistorial` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `bono` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `usuario` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `historialbonos`
--

INSERT INTO `historialbonos` (`codHistorial`, `bono`, `usuario`, `fecha`) VALUES
(2, 1, 1, '2020-11-20 12:52:29'),
(3, 1, 1, '2020-11-23 10:24:58'),
(4, 6, 1, '2020-11-23 10:54:54'),
(5, 1, 1, '2020-11-23 10:55:46'),
(6, 1, 1, '2020-11-23 10:58:22'),
(7, 6, 1, '2020-11-23 11:00:11'),
(8, 6, 1, '2020-11-23 11:01:15'),
(9, 6, 1, '2020-11-23 11:16:19'),
(10, 6, 1, '2020-11-23 11:30:23'),
(11, 1, 1, '2020-11-23 11:31:28'),
(12, 6, 1, '2020-11-23 11:43:28');

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `historialbonos`
--
ALTER TABLE `historialbonos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`codHistorial`),
  ADD KEY `historialbonos_usuario_foreign` (`usuario`),
  ADD KEY `historialbonos_bono_foreign` (`bono`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `historialbonos`
--
ALTER TABLE `historialbonos`
  MODIFY `codHistorial` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=13;

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `historialbonos`
--
ALTER TABLE `historialbonos`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `historialbonos_bono_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`bono`) REFERENCES `bonos` (`codBono`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `historialbonos_usuario_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`usuario`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);
```

**Tabla Contratan**

```
--
-- Base de datos: `bonosat`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `contratan`
--

CREATE TABLE `contratan` (
  `codContrato` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `bono` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `tiempoRestanteBono` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `bonoSolicitado` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `tiempoSolicitado` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `activo` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `usuario` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `contratan`
--

INSERT INTO `contratan` (`codContrato`, `fecha`, `bono`, `tiempoRestanteBono`, `bonoSolicitado`, `tiempoSolicitado`, `activo`, `usuario`) VALUES
(11, '2020-11-23 11:38:20', 6, 10, 1, 30, 0, 1);

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `contratan`
--
ALTER TABLE `contratan`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`codContrato`),
  ADD KEY `contratan_usuario_foreign` (`usuario`),
  ADD KEY `contratan_bono_foreign` (`bono`),
  ADD KEY `contratanBonoSoli_bono` (`bonoSolicitado`);
```

**Bonos**

```
    CREATE TABLE `bonos` (
  `codBono` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `minutos` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `precio` double(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `bonos`
--

INSERT INTO `bonos` (`codBono`, `tipo`, `minutos`, `precio`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, '1/2H', 30, 20.00, NULL, NULL),
(2, '1H', 60, 40.00, NULL, NULL),
(3, '5H', 300, 175.00, NULL, NULL),
(4, '10H', 600, 330.00, NULL, NULL),
(5, '24H', 1200, 600.00, NULL, NULL),
(6, '10Min', 10, 9.00, NULL, NULL);
```

**Asistencia**

```
CREATE TABLE `asistencia` (
  `codAsistencia` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `mensaje` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `usuario` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pendiente',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `asistencia`
--

INSERT INTO `asistencia` (`codAsistencia`, `fecha`, `mensaje`, `usuario`, `estado`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(2, '2020-11-23 11:25:29', 'Prueba Histórico', 1, 'pendiente', NULL, NULL),
(3, '2020-11-23 12:32:03', 'prueba', 1, 'pendiente', NULL, NULL);

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `asistencia`
--
ALTER TABLE `asistencia`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`codAsistencia`),
  ADD KEY `asistencia_usuario_foreign` (`usuario`);
```

Comment: @BetaM arroja el codigo de bono, necesito el tipo. Con mi actualización creo que lo he resuelto, no se si es la mejor forma

Comment: si finalmente la respuesta es la tuya, entiendo que puedes añadirla tú mismo a tu pregunta como respuesta para mejorar la calidad de la comunidad

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz hecho

Comment: Crea una respuesta!!!! ;) no hace falta añadirlo al enunciado, si no crear una respuesta. Es posible que tengas una limitación de unas horas hasta que te deje, o que quizá con tu puntuación en la página aún no tengas permiso, pero, es razonabe que si has encontrado la respuesta, añadas una Respuesta, no la aclaración en el enunciado ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIÓN

Creo que lo he resuelto haciendo una subconsulta en el select:

```
select bonos.codBono, users.nombre, bonos.tipo, bonos.minutos, bonos.precio, 
contratan.tiempoRestanteBono, (select DISTINCT tipo from bonos, contratan 
where contratan.bonoSolicitado = bonos.codBono group by codBono) as 
bonoSolicitado, contratan.tiempoSolicitado 
from contratan 
INNER join users on contratan.usuario = users.id 
INNER join bonos on contratan.bono = bonos.codBono where activo = 0
```